# Solution to check for metadata and add it if not present and modify it if it is using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an C# .NET control that writes a canonical url to the metadata of a page.

Code to be written: `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mysite.com">`

The jist of the code we are using look like this and works well.

```
private void setCanonicalURL(string href)
{
    HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();
    link.Href = href;
    link.Attributes.Add(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Rel.ToString().ToLower(), "canonical");
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);
}
```

A new issue we are facing is that this control is being used on sites where we have no control of the templates. At times other templates or controls are writing the canonical metadata.

What I'd like to do is check the head to see if there was a canonical link and if it is there modify it. If it is not there add it, but I can't find any documentation on how to do this. I have been investigating using the `Page.Header` without much luck.

Comment: How sure are you that your code will run last, and there won't be code that executes later, that will change the canonical header?

Comment: Not very sure to be honest. I was thinking about running this on Render, but am unclear how that might effect performance.